# Is RESTful API over-used/mis-used?

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I just spent a whole day reading the [Fielding's famous dissertation on REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm). It says at the [Conclusion](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/conclusions.htm) part that :

> REST, a novel architectural style for distributed **hypermedia** systems.
>   ...
>
> Although Web-based applications can include access to other styles of
>   interaction, the central focus of its protocol and performance
>   concerns is distributed hypermedia. **REST elaborates only those
>   portions of the architecture that are considered essential for
>   Internet-scale distributed hypermedia interaction**.

And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermedia):

> **Hypermedia**, an extension of the term hypertext, is a nonlinear medium
>   of information which includes graphics, audio, video, plain text and
>   hyperlinks.

So it appears to me REST is kind of meant for `web-based content-intensive system`. But obviously `RESTful API` has been a `buzzword` used in almost everywhere regarding `web service`.

So is this kind of **over-use**? Or **mis-use**?

Refs:

[RESTful APIs, the big lie.](https://mmikowski.github.io/the_lie/)

[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

[What does "hypermedia data formats" mean in Fielding's famous dissertation when talking about Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372089/what-does-hypermedia-data-formats-mean-in-fieldings-famous-dissertation-when)

Answer (score 5):

I think JSON is not more or less media than text or video are. So in essence, a serialized object represented in JSON is a medium.

Now "hypermedia" is media that is linked together semantically. You *can* make JSON hypermedia by including links: [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language), or [HATEAOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

Herein you add links to related resources to a JSON document. [Example](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS):

```
{
    "content": [ {
        "price": 499.00,
        "description": "Apple tablet device",
        "name": "iPad",
        "links": [ {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/product/1"
        } ],
        "attributes": {
            "connector": "socket"
        }
    }, {
        "price": 49.00,
        "description": "Dock for iPhone/iPad",
        "name": "Dock",
        "links": [ {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/product/3"
        } ],
        "attributes": {
            "connector": "plug"
        }
    } ],
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "product.search",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/product/search"
    } ]
}
```

People argue that without links, JSON is not hypermedia.

I'm also a big fan of not trying to cram every API into REST. Not every API is about *resources*, so if your API represents RPC instead, call it what it is: an RPC API.

Comment: I always had the same line of thinking. I don't get why people make serious excuses to call their API's REST. It seems they are afraid to say so! Weird!